# Mysql lock table - Does it hold only one lock of table in a transaction?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to test the `INNODB_LOCKS` as following.

I create a `test1` and `test2` table and add serveral records at the beginning.

In the first transaction.

```
 begin
 
 lock table test1 write;  # locked the `test1` table immediately at the first step
 
 lock table test2 write;  # blocked as the 3rd step
```

In the second transaction.

```
begin

lock table test2 write; # locked the `test2` table immediately at the second step

lock table test1 write; # locked the `test1` table immediately at the 4th step and the 3rd step unblocked
```

seems that it only can hold one lock of table in a transaction. anyone knows the deep reason?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#table-lock-release *If a session issues a LOCK TABLES statement to acquire a lock while already holding locks, its **existing locks are released implicitly** before the new locks are granted.* If you want to lock test2 in addition to test1 lock you must lock both tables in 2nd LOCK statement.

Comment: Note, this is table level locking, not innodb's row level locking.